# Multi-channel audio input to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, signal-processing, microphone

I wanted to know if Unity3D supports multi-channel audio input. I am trying to use an audio interface to input and process stereo audio in Unity.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Unity supports multiple simultaneous input devices (see [Microphone](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html)), but assumes only one channel per device. This a a bit of a limitation for multi channel device users.

I worked around it for my project by routing each input channel from my sound card to a virtual device, so that each device that Unity interacts with contains only a single input channel. You can do this using [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) or [VoiceMeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm), for example.